# hibernate does not recognize an already defined constraint in database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I mapped a relationship at the database level, the name of the relationship is **FK_CLASSIFICATION_FRUITS** defined using sql server relationship mapping at the db level. 
In my Java application, I have an entity mapping in Fruits class to sit on the already defined relationship shown below:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASSIFICATION_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Classification clasiFk;
```

The above entity mapping is to establish a relationship between Classification and Fruits and this has already been defined in the database level.

When I try to run my application, I get this error prompt

```
     ... 90 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to ex
ecute schema management to JDBC target [alter table [FRUITS] add
 constraint FKdctshrn0ebh90up9sh5125nbb foreign key ([CLASSIFICATION_FK]) references
 [CLASSIFICATION]]
```

more of the stacktrace

```
    ... 88 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The ALTER TABLE stat
ement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKdctshrn0ebh90up9sh5125nbb ".
The conflict occurred in database "cyz", table "dbo.CLASSIFICATION", column '
ID'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError
(SQLServerException.java:232)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServ
erStatement.java:1672)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQ
LServerStatement.java:903)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute
(SQLServerStatement.java:796)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLSe
rverConnection.java:2438)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLSer
verStatement.java:208)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLS
erverStatement.java:183)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServ
erStatement.java:721)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(Sta
tementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDa
tabaseImpl.java:56)
        ... 98 more
```

The above is because, it is not recognizing the already defined constraint

Please how can I inform hibernate that the relationship has already been defined in db

Comment: Please post DDL of the current state of the schema and provide the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: do u mean at the db level?

Comment: If you code like - @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Classification clasiFk; It should work.

Comment: I should remove this >>> referencedColumnName @HasanuzzamanRana

Comment: Please try with that code @user10445503

Comment: so what will be the JoinColumn name if I remove it

Comment: you are mentioning type of variable as entity name, that means you are assining an entity (table) as a variable type(custom object), so when you mention name parameter that will connect used custom type "id" field, as like you trying to connect via referenceColumnName

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with , By providing  fetching type and null able false

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLASSIFICATION_FK", nullable = false)
Classification clasiFk;
```